# How can I copy this method of making an array in Python as I do with PHP?

Tags: python, arrays

I am looking to recreate the following from PHP to Python:

```
<?php

$data["test step 1"]["sets"][] = "CV_1";
$data["test step 1"]["sets"][] = "NV_2";
```

I looked into using defaultdict with Python and I tried to use:

```
self.word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"][] = heading
```

But then `[]` does not work in the example above. I think I don't quite understand how Pythons data structures work coming from the PHP world. Is this possible to do in Python? In PHP I want to use the `[]` at the end because I am not sure how many elements I will be adding.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to checkout the official python documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences with how you append items to lists/arrays between PHP and Python.

You can start by defining

```
self.word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"]
```

as an empty array like so:

```
self.word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"] = []
```

once you have done that you can append items to the array using:

```
self.word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"].append('heading')
```

Now `self.word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"]` has the value of `['heading']`

If you were to do

```
self.word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"].append('2nd one')
```

after the first append it would now have the value `['heading','2nd one']`

Answer (score 1):

Python has lists and dictionaries. The `list` in Python is similar to an array. I think what is called a `dict` in Python is called an associative array in PHP.

How to use lists:

```
a_list = []  # same as: a_list = list()
a_list.append('value')
a_list.append('foobar')
print(a_list)  # gives: ['value', 'foobar']
```

How to use dictionaries:

```
a_dict = {}  # same as: a_dict = dict()
a_dict['key'] = 'value'
a_dict['foo'] = 'bar'
print(a_dict)  # gives: {'key': 'value', 'foo': 'bar'}
```

For detailed information, look at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but maybe:

```
word_test_case = {}
word_test_case["test step 1"] = {}
word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"] = []
```

Now the value of `word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"]` is a Python `list` (an array). With

```
word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"].append(value)
```

you can add values to that `list`.

Comment: I understand this but how could I reproduce what I have done in PHP?

Comment: If you understand it, it should be trivial. If you don't you can show what you did.

Comment: With your latest update, if I were to do `word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"] = "heading2"` it will overwrite the first heading?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "first heading". In my example, nothing is overwritten, just inserted. Bust simply use the interactive console and `print(word_test_case)` to see. It is always the pattern that you assign a value to a key.

Comment: I am looking to store an array of strings within  word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"] if that makes sense?

Comment: This is what the answer does.

Comment: @MartinThoma your answer currently stores a string in `word_test_case["test step 1"]["sets"]` to store an array you would need to change `"heading"` to `["heading"]`

Comment: @casualcoder Oops, I missed the "an array of" part of the comment.

Comment: @casualcoder But in PHP I can do `$var["test"]["test 2"][] = "test" and in Python this does not work. I want to be able to keep adding to the array?

Comment: @tty2018 look at my answer i clarified that part for you